# Layout with UITableView and CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a question in developing a layout for an application.

The basic structure is a Slide at the top and a news feed below. Similar to Instagram layout.

As I'm new to Swift / IOS programming, I have some doubts, such as:

```
Structure:
-TABLEWVIEW
--TABLEVIEWCELL - SLIDE_TOP
----COLLECTIONVIEW
------COLLECTIONVIEWCELL - SLIDES
--TABLEVIEWCELL - FEED_NEWS
---- ????
```

Example of layout structure, as in the image:
[image]

My big question is whether in FEED I use a COLLECTIONVIEW again or continue with TABLEVIEWCELL.

How this layout template is handled by developers. I would like some idea or help in this regard.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a layout as follows:

- Create a global `UIScrollView`
- Add one UICollectionView for the top horizontal slide as the first child
- Add a second `UICollectionView` below to handle the main vertical slide